# Django returning 404 for static files

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404

When running a Django project on my local Mac server I get 404 errors when trying to access static files.

My directory structure looks like:

```
myapp/static
```

In my settings.py I have tried a variety of combinations of the following:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
    '/var/www/myapp/static',
    '/pycharmprojects/myapp/static'
]

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
)
```

For every use of a static file I get an error like this in PyCharm:

```
GET /static/img/pastedsvg%2017.svg HTTP/1.1" 404 101
```

And an error like this in Firefox:

```
GET 
http://127.0.0.1:8888/static/img/pastedsvg%2017.svg [HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND 15ms]
```

I have looked at other answers to this problem in Stackoverflow and tried the suggestions but so far nothing works.

Comment: are u serving the file via apache/nginx?

Comment: It is the default Mac server which is Apache I think? But I am not sure how to determine exactly what server is being used.

Comment: ok so did you have to execute manage.py runserver?

Comment: if you are serving from apache, make sure the directory setting is right.

Comment: I use PyCharm and am using the Run command from the Run menu to launche the app and server.

Comment: How do I check the Apache directory settings?

Comment: I have no idea on how to use pycharm and how it is configured. But I believe that should be fairly easy to google.

Comment: Thanks Mox. I have tried Googling this without luck but will persevere :)

Comment: If you are not running in debug mode, have you run `collectstatic`?  `python -m django collectstatic`

Comment: Also, another observation, the path assigned to `STATIC_ROOT` should not be included in `STATICFILES_DIRS`.  I wasn't sure if `/pycharmprojects/myapp/static` was maybe your `STATIC_ROOT`.

Comment: The local path to the static files is: /Users/billnoble/PycharmProjects/mydir/static

I have run collectstatic

Comment: If you are using PyCharm, you are most likely using the Django runserver to server your website (not Apache).  To confirm, when you run your app, click on the `Run` tab at the bottom of PyCharm and scroll to the top of that window.  You should see something like `python manage.py runserver 8000`.

Comment: Thanks for that CaffeineFueled. Yes I can see 'manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8888'

How can I check what the server directory settings are?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is difficult to tell what exactly the issue might be, but here are some observations that may help:

1. `STATIC_ROOT` is only used for `collectstatic`.  It is where `collectstatic` will copy your static files when you run it from the command line (`python -m django collectstatic`).
2. `STATIC_ROOT` should not be included in `STATICFILES_DIRS` as this would confuse `collectstatic` since its job is to copy static files from your static directories to `STATIC_ROOT`.
3. `AppDirectoriesFinder` is going to look for static files in a directory called `static` under each of your apps.  So, for example, if your project is located in `/pycharmprojects/myapp/`, `AppDirectoriesFinder` will look for static files in directories such as `/pycharmprojects/myapp/anapp/static` and `/pycharmprojects/myapp/anotherapp/static` (for each application listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`) and copy them to `STATIC_ROOT`.
4. `FileSystemFinder` is going to use the values in `STATICFILES_DIRS` to look for static files and copy them to `STATIC_ROOT` (which is why your value for `STATIC_ROOT` should not be listed in `STATICFILES_DIRS`).
5. When in debug mode, you do not need to `collectstatic` as Django will look for files in their original location, but when not debug mode (`DEBUG = False` in your Django config file), you will need to run `collectstatic` in order for Django to find your static files.

So, from this, I suggest:

1. Definitely remove `os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')` from your `STATICFILES_DIR`
2. Probably remove `/pycharmprojects/myapp/static` from your `STATICFILES_DIR` if that points to the same location as `os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')`
3. If you are not running in debug mode (`DEBUG = True` in your Django config file), run `collectstatic` from the command line so that Django can see your static files.

One other question.  To which directory is your `BASE_DIR` pointing?  It seems like `PROJECT_DIR` might be redundant since it's pointing to where `BASE_DIR` usually points.

Hopefully something in this wall of text will be helpful.

Cheers!

Comment: Huge thanks for the detailed info! I have tried with both Debug True and False. My static files are contained in /pycharmprojects/mdir/static and not in /pycharmprojects/mydir/myapp/static. I have cut down the relevant code in settings.py to just:

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

Still getting 404 though

Comment: Hmm... so let's run with `DEBUG = True`. And I'm guessing at your directory structure here from your many replies (so fix as appropriate), but make sure `/Users/billnoble/PycharmProjects/mydir/static` is listed in `STATICFILES_DIRS`. Make sure the file `/Users/billnoble/PycharmProjects/mydir/static/img/pastedsvg 17.svg` exists. I don't know Macs at all, so I don't know how they handle case sensitivity, but just to be extra sure, make sure the path and file names match the casing of the directories and files. Let's see if we can get at least this one file working.

Comment: I have DEBUG = FALSE, but I am confused about the including "/Users/billnoble/PycharmProjects/mdir/static" in the STATICFILES_DIRS. In your main reply did you not say that STATIC_ROOT should not be included in STATICFILES_DIRS?

Comment: My apologies.  I meant `DEBUG = True`.  Is `/Users/billnoble/PycharmProjects/mydir/static` where you expect static files to end up after `collectstatic` or is it where your source static files live?  Keeping the focus to just one file for right now, where does your source `pastedsvg 17.svg` live?  That's the directory that needs to go in `STATICFILES_DIRS` (if it's not already in a `static` subdirectory under an app).

Comment: /Users/billnoble/PycharmProjects/mydir/static is where I keep the source static files (which is why I am not sure why I need the collectstatic or STATICFILES_DIRS bits). The .svg file lives in the static folder under the img directory. I have tried the following with both debug true and false:

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]

Comment: As long as we keep `DEBUG = True` for now, `collectstatic` and `STATIC_ROOT` should not affect anything.  `STATICFILES_DIR` is necessary because static files are being stored under the project (instead of under an app).  We need to let Django know to look there.  To do this, we need to ensure that either `/Users/billnoble/PycharmProjects/mydir/static` or `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')` is listed in `STATICFILES_DIRS`.  In your example, you have `/pycharmprojects/myapp/static` listed, which I believe is incorrect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104653/discussion-between-caffeinefueled-and-bill-noble).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that the following is the correct answer, but I hope it will go well.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    # os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
print("PROJECT_ROOT", PROJECT_ROOT)
print("BASE_DIR", BASE_DIR)
```

In this case, the value of the variable named *PROJECT_ROOT* is the same directory that exists setting file.
That is why it's not **PROJECT_ROOT** exactly.

You can execute when running server even if writing python-code in setting file. So you can verify that the code was written in properly once again.

Comment: Thanks Kerorin. When trying this I get "/Users/billnoble/PycharmProjects/cues2/myapp" for the PROJECT_ROOT and "/Users/billnoble/PycharmProjects/myapp" for the BASE_DIR. I am still getting the 404 errors though.

Comment: "/Users/billnoble/PycharmProjects/cues2/myapp" and "/Users/billnoble/PycharmProjects/myapp" ... I guess this is obvious

Comment: Sorry that was a typo! Should have been "/Users/billnoble/PycharmProjects/mydir/myapp" for PROJECT_ROOT and "/Users/billnoble/PycharmProjects/mydir" for BASE_DIR

Comment: Hmm... which place is the _static directory_?

Comment: /Users/billnoble/PycharmProjects/mydir/static

Comment: Wow... it's so strange. Is there `img/pastedsvg 17.svg` in this directory really? If not, you can try to run `./manage.py collectstatic`. Perhaps it might cause the problem to be resolved. However in my inspiration, it doesn't hit  the jackpot.